# HttpInterceptor and AuthGuard are blocking each other

Tags: angular, architecture

I poorly design my authorization system. And I need advise to correct few errors.

I created :

- an HttpInterceptor to:

  - set JWT token in header on each request (it's kept in localStorage)
  - retrieve and update JWT token from response (each authorized request send back an updated token in header response)
  - on 401 errors, redirect the user to login page
- an AuthGuard to:

  - put it on some route
  - check if user is authorized if not redirect to login page
- a UserService that:

  - keep in a BehaviorSubject the current user
  - try to refresh current user if a JWT token is stored in localStorage

My usecase is:

1. user try to directly load a page with restricted authorization
2. the guard load UserService to verify that user is logged in
3. the UserService make http call
4. HttpInterceptor get request as there is no token in localStrorage, it doesn't take the token
5. the back as there is no token send a 401
6. the interceptor intercept the response catch the 401 and return a null
7. as the response is turn into a null, it never reach back the UserService which won't allow the Guard to resolve the route (then the navigate made in 401 interceptor won't be ever call)

For complete code, [here is the complete GitHub repo](https://github.com/asirko/JumpPong) and more precisly:

- [HttpInterceptor](https://github.com/asirko/JumpPong/blob/master/src/app/shared/token-interceptor.service.ts)
- [AuthGuard](https://github.com/asirko/JumpPong/blob/master/src/app/shared/auth.guard.ts)
- [UserService](https://github.com/asirko/JumpPong/blob/master/src/app/features/users/user.service.ts)

How to make the interceptor return an empty response instead of null? I suppose would be enough to solve the problem.
Or should I do a complete different pattern ?

Comment: For anyone having question about this, it's normal the way guard and interceptor are designed.
First all guard are tested (from the root route to the child route), then the resolver are played.
Now, I rarely use resolver especially if the data resolved is used in guard